# I/O stream library in C?

Tags: c, stream

Recently, I had to implement a stream library, [libstream](https://github.com/vzxwco/libstream), for one of my projects. Basically, it's a `char`-FIFO implemented as a linked list storing chunks of 4k bytes each (instead of one large chunk), with wrapper functions such as `read()`, `write()` and `peek()`.

Seemingly, there's nothing comparable available on the net, at least not as a stand-alone library.

Hence my question: why isn't there a common, generic, publicly available stream library for C as described above?

Comment: Why would I want this? As opposed to just not using it and doing whatever needed to be done with plain `stdio.h`.

Comment: Iskar: In my case, it's for an event-driven networking library. The `stdio.h` functions either store their stream data in one large buffer, or they don't allow to `peak()` more than one `char`.

Comment: shouldn't `peak()` be `peek()` ?

Comment: @Philip Isn't the point of `peek()` to look at only one char? The frontmost one... If you are looking at more than that, aren't you really just reading the stream and then moving the cursor/pointer back to where it started from?

Comment: @Iskar: In principle, yes. In my scenario, there's a bunch of recognizer functions, along with their corresponding handler functions. Each recognizer will peek some data from the stream in order to decide whether this data can be processed by its handler or not. If it doesn't, the next recognizer function needs a seemingly untouched screen. Think of recognizer functions as a way to implement something like events.

Comment: @ninjalj: my shabby English! Thanks+fixed.

Comment: @Philip This is looking more and more like you're just using a linked list with FIFO access to do some parsing, which is not really an I/O stream at all...

Comment: I mean, was there anything stopping you using a library implementation of a linked list with 4KiB character blocks at each node to do this instead? Also, are you familiar with `ungetc()`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to make your own 'stream' wrapper with select and non blocking I/O? Use something like a packet header and read whole packets at the time depending on the data length defined in the header? Normally you don't want to `peek` in a buffer... this means you would first `peek`->`parse` then `read`->`parse`? Double actions are bad. Especially in a driver...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an I/O Stream library from A&T Research under *Common Public License 1.0*, called **[SFIO: A Safe/Fast I/O Library](http://www2.research.att.com/~gsf/download/ref/sfio/sfio.html)** which you might want to give a look. It is downloadable **[here](http://www2.research.att.com/~gsf/cgi-bin/download.cgi?action=list&name=sfio)**.

It is difficult to answer Why there are no generic more commonly available stream libraries in open domain because pretty much everything in the Open Source domain comes through whims and wishes of the contributors who are willing to put in the effort.

Comment: Looks like not available in those two old links.